# Why it comes five 0 why not 1 to 5

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, dynamic-memory-allocation

i expect to have 1 to 5 in my Array but it comes five 0 instead can you plz explain about it.
Thanks.

```
int anzahl=5, i;    
int[] Schubladen = new int[anzahl];    
for (i=0;i<anzahl; i++)    
{    
    Console.WriteLine(Schubladen[i]);    
}
```

Comment: Start by posting a well formatted code sample. Then don't spam tags.

Comment: Why do you expect a newly created array to contain those numbers?

Comment: "i expect to have 1 to 5 in my Array" - why? you never assign values in this array.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(i);` ?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) Console.WriteLine(i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have values in your array, it contains only garbage, at the first you need initialize it

```
 int anzahl=5, i;    
 int[] Schubladen = new int[anzahl];    
 std::fill( Schubladen, anzahl, 0 );
 for (i=0;i<anzahl; i++)    
 {    
     std::cout<<Schubladen[i];    
 }
```

Comment: It won't contain garbage. Array elements are default initialised – zero for numeric types – in .NET.

Comment: `std:fill`, `std:cout`... question is marked C# not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, in your code you didn't initialize the array and trying to write its items in the console.if you want to output index of the array then you can use:

```
Console.WriteLine(i);
```